# *ngIf statement inside html Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #filterBox [disabled]="!!toggleButton.value.length" />
  <mat-label *ngIf="toggleButton?.value?.length <= 0">Search box</mat-label>
  <mat-label *ngIf="toggleButton?.value?.length > 0">Search box is blocked</mat-label>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-button-toggle-group #toggleButton="matButtonToggleGroup" multiple="">
  <mat-button-toggle value="TEST1">1</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="TEST2">2</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="TEST3">3</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

So what I want achive. If button from button-toggle-group will be pressed I want see disabled input and in label "Search box is blocked".

Also remeber that If I will press 1 and 2 buttons I also  I want see disabled input and in label "Search box is blocked". Is this possbile

Comment: Your code should work just fine if you remove the `.length` part. Have you tried that? `[disabled]="!!toggleButton.value"` should do the trick.

Comment: In such combination input is blocked from start

Comment: I just tested it on stack blitz, what exactly does not work with your code? It should work just fine as it is.

Comment: can you post stack blitz maybe I am doing somenthing wrong :( also do you have suggestion about *ngIf ?

Comment: I cannot post a stackblitz. I just looked at how the button toggle behaves whenever it is clicked by editing the [example from the documentation page](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview). Can you elaborate more on what is the behavior that you want? Why is the code that you included in your question not working for you?

Comment: If button from mat-button-toggle will pressed => disabled input and I want see string "Search box is blocked". If any button is not pressed I want see string "Search box" and working input. I have problem with *ngIf="toggleButton?.value?.length

Comment: Yes. The _I have problem_ part is what I cannot understand. What problem do you have? If you want to see _Search box_ or _Search box is blocked_, just replace `h1` with `mat-hint` instead.

Comment: sorry I did mistakte It should be mat-label   

 <mat-label *ngIf="toggleButton?.value?.length <= 0">Search box</mat-label>
  <mat-label *ngIf="toggleButton?.value?.length > 0">Search box is blocked</mat-label>


If  any button is pressed I want see disable input and in label >Search box is blocked

Comment: And now what happens when you toggle the buttons? Does the label text change?

Comment: Nothing happen now  :(

Comment: I would try what Octavian said but with a small change. Do also a check if the toggleButton?.value != null.  It will be nice if we could see the values you receive in toggleButton. I'm not really sure that you are getting something there.